# How to get the JSON object

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Ok so here is a question.

I have two projects in code igniter, say a and b.
I have a form in 'a'. When ever a user fills in a form and submits it all the data from the form is put in to an array and then json encoded. here is the code for it

```
function create(){
$data = array(); //get all the data from the form into an array
$data[] = array('name' => $this->input->post('name'),
    'abbrev' => $this->input->post('abbrev'),
    'long_name' => $this->input->post('long_name'),
    'long_abbrev' => $this->input->post('long_abbrev'),
    'url' => $this->input->post('url'),
    'description' => $this->input->post('description') ); 
    $json_data=json_encode($data);
    $this->output->set_output($json_data)
   }
```

Now I want to send this data to project 'b' where it will store it in the database. here is the code for it.
      $college_details = array();
                $college_details['colleges']=
        json_decode(file_get_contents('http://localhost:8888/a/colleges'));

But i don't know how project 'b' will know that there is data to be taken

Comment: Please code samples of the relevant parts from `localhost/a/college/index.php`. We can't read files on your harddrive ;) Also state how you'd like to retrieve the data, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Well, common practice would be to include/require one file into another, so you can use the contents of both. Or you could also put the data in a $_SESSION and redirect to the other file. Really, we need more information on the relationship between the two files to give you a more useful answer.

Comment: If you want just to send data from the form on site `a` to form on site `b`, without any processing, then all you need is to `<form action="http://site.b/etc/">` and to get the data as you would normally. If it's not the case, then you should use cURL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you mean is that you want to store the data across a session so you can access it on the next page. If this is the case, use the PHP session functionality (add `session_start()` at the top of each file) to store the variable across the pages (`$_SESSION['data'] = $data;` on page one and `echo $_SESSION['data'];` on page two).

Answer (score -1):

as i understand  you have this senario
project a) at ://project_a/
project b) at ://project_b/

at project a ://project_a/some_action you are submitting your form and generating json string as $json_data. And you want to project b to save this data.

SOLUTION 
$jason_data is a string call ://project_b/json_save_action buy CURL at the submition of form and pass the $json_data as a variable to ://project_b/json_save_action.
let me know if it helps. :)

Comment: You mean to say to this $json_data=json_encode($data);
  $this->curl->simple_post('http://localhost:8888/b/colleges', $json_data);

Comment: yes exactly ....... file_get_contents will also work if you pass in url after urlencode

Comment: good yo hear that, can you please accept the answer by clicking right sign.